# Log graph question

Tags: standard-deviation, logarithm, quantiles, self-study

So let's say you have a distribution where X is the 16% quantile. Then you take the log of all the values of the distribution. Would log(X) still be the 16% quantile in the log distribution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Quantiles can be transformed under any monotonically increasing transformation.

To see this, suppose $Y$ is the random variable and $q_{0.16}$ is the 16% quantile. Then 
$$
\text{Pr}(Y\le q_{0.16}) = \text{Pr}(\log(Y)\le\log(q_{0.16})) = 0.16.
$$
Generally, if $f$ is monotonic and increasing then
$$
\text{Pr}(Y\le q_{\alpha}) = \text{Pr}(f(Y)\le f(q_{\alpha})) = \alpha.
$$

Comment: Monotonic *and increasing*, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

When you say that "X is the 16% quantile", what it means is that 16% of the sample have a lower value than X. The log of any number smaller than X is smaller than log(X) and the log of any number greater than X is greater than log(X), so the ordering is not changed.